# How to use Python's re to insert an integer?

Tags: python

I'm currently using Python to search through a .config file and look for an integer in a line such as "locationId="225".

It replaces the integer such as 225 with another number of my choosing.
This works fine.  However, I'm not sure how to enter my own number if the original .config file is missing a number.  Example:

```
    locationID=""
```

So if the original locationId is missing an integer, I still want to replace it with my new integer.

I have used:

```
import re

sys.stdout.write(re.sub(r'(locationid=")', r'\1 ' + newtext, line))
```

but this causes it to output something such as

```
    locationId=" 33"
```

with a space before the 33.  How to I remove the space before the 33 and make it output

```
    locationId="33"
```

?

I basically just want to know how to remove the space before the number.

Comment: Why is there a space in `r'\1 '` ?

Comment: Let me try removing it again.  When i renoved the space before, it was giving me an error.  I'll double-check it.

Comment: Oh, I see the problem now. Removing that space causes a different problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space is coming from your replacement string, `r'\1 '`, but removing that space causes a problem when you concatenate a number, say, 1, with it. If `newtext` is 1 then the replacement string becomes `r'\11'` without the space.

Remove the double quote from the capturing group and add it to the replacement string:

```
re.sub(r'(locationid=)"', r'\1"' + newtext, line)
```